# Check touch device using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I have a small function that detects if my user is on a touch device that works perfectly...

```
function is_touch_device() {        
    return (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
}
if(!is_touch_device()) {
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
}
```

I want to add a condition that if the device is an ipad, then don't carry out the redirect.

I've tried...

```
function is_touch_device() {

            var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

            if( !isiPad ){
                return (('ontouchstart' in window)
                || (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0)
                || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
            }

        };

        if(!is_touch_device()) {
            window.location.href = 'index.html';
        }
```

But it stops touch devices redirecting, all of them in fact, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need a function and try this script;

```
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        alert('Mobile device, exclude iPad');
    }
    else {
        alert('Desktop');
    }
```